# Convert entity to keyboard character using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am in need to convert `&#x00A0;` entity to normal space (keyboard space) using XSLT 1.0. But I am getting the entity `&#160;` instead of space.

**Sample XML:**

```
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<math display='block'>
 <mrow>
  <mtext>x&#x00A0;y&#x00A0;+&#x00A0;y&#x00A0;x</mtext>
 </mrow>
</math>
</chapter>
```

**XSLT 1.0 tried:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mtext">
<xsl:for-each select="contains(.,'&#x00A0;')">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><math display="block"><mrow><mtext>x y + y x</mtext></mrow></math></chapter>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><math display="block"><mrow><mtext>x&#160;y&#160;+&#160;y&#160;x</mtext></mrow></math></chapter>
```

Comment: could you add the output that you got with your attempt?

Comment: @Treemonkey: Please find the output which i got

Comment: siva2012, There exists a much simpler solution -- do have a look.

Comment: Don't use disable-output-escaping. Especially when there's nothing to escape - it's just noise. An XSLT 1.0 processor should give you an error on this because the select attribute of your xsl:for-each instruction evaluates to a boolean, not a node-set. The only reason you're not getting an error is that your template rule isn't actually matching, because you forgot to quality match="mtext" with the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mtext">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="from">&#x00A0;</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="to" select="' '"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="from"/>
    <xsl:param name="to"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $from)">
        <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($text, $from)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($text, $from)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="concat($before, $to)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$before"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$to" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$after"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am getting the correct output using this XSLT

Comment: I can't see why it works, the problem of "mtext" not being namespace-qualified is still there.

Answer (score 4):

**Much simpler**:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#xA0;', ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#xA0;', ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<math display='block'>
 <mrow>
  <mtext>x&#x00A0;y&#x00A0;+&#x00A0;y&#x00A0;x</mtext>
 </mrow>
</math>
</chapter>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <math display="block">
      <mrow>
         <mtext>x y + y x</mtext>
      </mrow>
   </math>
</chapter>
```

**Remember**:

The best way to replace a single character with another character (or to delete it) is to use the standard XPath function **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)**.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I never thought that this would work as i assumed that it would take &#xA0; as a string

Comment: @Treemonkey, The string `&#xA0;` is actually a *character entity* and is converted by the XML parser to the single character that this entity denotes. The XSLT processor sees this as a single character and doesn't actually know there was an entity substitution. Regardless whether `&#xA0;` was used or `&#160;` was used, the XSLT processor sees just the same character.